# Chaining and statements in sql

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I've created a database for movies. Just as practice. I added tags for movies like "romance, action, animated, female main character, male main character,...." and so on. Each movie has an id and is linked over an extra table with the id of the corresponding tags. So now, when I want to send a query in which I look for multiple tags and ask for a movie title in return, I get nothing despite a movie excisting in the DB which includes those tags. I feel like my mistake is somewhere in my query but I don't see where. Someone an idea? The query looks like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  movie.title
FROM
  movie
JOIN
  movie_tags ON movie.id = movie_tags.movie_id
JOIN
  tags ON movie_tags.tag_id = tags.id
WHERE
  tags.name = 'animated' && 'male main character'
ORDER BY
  title ASC
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking for movies with both tags, then the query that you are looking for is this:

```
SELECT m.title
FROM movie m JOIN
     movie_tags mt
     ON m.id = mt.movie_id JOIN
     tags t
     ON mt.tag_id = t.id
WHERE t.name IN ('animated', 'male main character')
GROUP BY title ASC
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT t.name) = 2;
```

Notes:

- Use table aliases and qualified column names, especially if you are learning SQL.  This is a good habit.
- The expression:  `t.name = 'animated' and t.name = 'male main character' is obviously never going to be true.`t.name` cannot have both values.
- The `GROUP BY` brings all the rows for a movie title together.  To be honest, `SELECT DISTINCT` is almost never the right construct; much more often, you want `GROUP BY`.
- The `HAVING` clause specifies that both tags are on the movie.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try this. :)

Comment: Worked perfectly, thanks. Now, I'll just have to edit my PHP code :)

Answer (score -2):

U cant use && to concatenate 'animated' && 'male main character'

Use tags.name = 'animated' AND tags.name = 'male main character'

Comment: Yeah my bad. I am writing in PHP so the habit of using && came through :P

Comment: *"U cant use &&"* - `&&` is perfectly valid https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/logical-operators.html Edit: @airbeat not "your bad". This answer is incorrect.